# How do I stop NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'll keep this short. I don't know why I'm getting NumberFormatException in my code. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void loadFiles() throws IOException {

        Info i = new Info();
        Song s = new Song();
        int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5, f = 6, g = 7;



        s.id = i.getSongTxt(a);
        s.titulo = i.getSongTxt(b);
        String ano = i.getSongTxt(c);
        s.id1 = i.getSongArtistsTxt(a);
        s.artista = i.getSongArtistsTxt(b);
        s.id2 = i.getSongDetailsTxt(a);
        String tempo = i.getSongDetailsTxt(b);
        String explicita = i.getSongDetailsTxt(c);
        String popularidade = i.getSongDetailsTxt(d);
        String dancabilidade = i.getSongDetailsTxt(e);
        String vivacidade = i.getSongDetailsTxt(f);
        String volume = i.getSongDetailsTxt(g);

        String[] ano1 = new String[ano.length()];
        String[] tempo1 = new String[tempo.length()];
        String[] explicita1 = new String[explicita.length()];
        String[] popularidade1 = new String[popularidade.length()];
        String[] dancabilidade1 = new String[dancabilidade.length()];
        String[] vivacidade1 = new String[vivacidade.length()];
        String[] volume1 = new String[volume.length()];

        ano = ano.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        ano1 = ano.split(" ");
        tempo1 = tempo.split("");

        for(int n = 0; n < 7; n++){
            s.ano[n] = Integer.parseInt(ano1[n]);
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ano1));


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Info i = new Info();
        loadFiles();
    }
}
```

and this is what the error looks like.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[2012,2013,2012,2013,2012,2013,2012]"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:660)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:778)
at pt.ulusofona.aed.deisiRockstar2021.Main.loadFiles(Main.java:44)
at pt.ulusofona.aed.deisiRockstar2021.Main.main(Main.java:55)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Any ideas as to why it's giving me this error?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

[Read the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html).

> Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format.

Your input string `"[2012,2013,2012,2013,2012,2013,2012]"` is not a number. So that input cannot be processed as a number.

Answer (score 1):

> "Any ideas as to why it's giving me this error?"

Simple. The thing you are giving it to parse as a number ... is not a number. Look at the error message.

---

> "How do I stop it?"

Look at how you (supposedly) splitting the `ano` string.

```
    ano = ano.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    ano1 = ano.split(" ");
```

That says:

1. Replace all whitespace with ... nothing.  That is: remove all whitespace.
2. Split using a single space as the separator.

Which plainly doesn't make sense.  You have removed the very characters that you are telling `split` to split on!

But that's wrong anyway, because the actual string you are attempting to process clearly also contains `','`, `'['` and `']'` characters, and they shouldn't be part of the number strings.

So what you need to do is redesign the way you are splitting the `ano` string into a sequence of number strings ... so that it will work with your input.

Hint: find and read the javadocs for `String.split(...)` and `Pattern`.